# How to check if a YouTube channel is active

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

It looks regardless of whether a channel has been created by a user, the youtube api will return a channel for that particular user.

Java API

```
YouTube.Channels.List search = youTube.get().channels().list("id);
search.setPart("id");
ChannelListResponse res = search.execute();
List<Channel> searchResultList = search.getItems()
Channel channel = searchResultList.get(0); // there is always a channel
```

For the authenticated user, the channel seems to exist but when going to the YouTube profile, it states "You must create a channel to upload videos. Create a channel" or if going to the url without the user being authenticated, it'll say "This channel is not available at the moment. Please try again later."

How do check that a youtube channel is active or not. do i have to attempt to upload to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

When you make an API call such as playlist management or video uploading, if there is no linked channel, the API will throw a GoogleJsonResponseException. Here's a code snippet showing you what happens when you try to make a playlist update API call and there's no channel:

```
try {
    yt.playlistItems().insert("snippet,contentDetails", playlistItem).execute();
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
    for(GoogleJsonError.ErrorInfo errorInfo : error.getErrors()) {
        if(errorInfo.getReason().equals("youtubeSignupRequired")) {
        // Ask the user to create a channel and link their profile   
        }
     }
}
```

You'll want to do something when you get "youtubeSignupRequired" as the reason for the error.

The other way is to check ahead of time. Make a Channel.List call and check for "items/status". You're looking for the boolean value "isLinked" to equal "true". Note that I've inserted a cast in this sample code because in the version of this sample, the client was returning a String value instead of a typed Boolean:

```
YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("status");
channelRequest.setMine("true");
channelRequest.setFields("items/status");
ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();
List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();
for (Channel channel : channelsList) {
    Map<String, Object> status = (Map<String, Object>) channel.get("status");
    if (true == (Boolean) status.get("isLinked")) {
        // Channel is linked to a Google Account
    } else {
        // Channel is NOT linked to a Google Account
    }
}
```

Comment: NP Aaron. If this is the best answer, it'd be really helpful if you set this question as answered so it doesn't pop up in my feeds when I'm looking for people to help!

Comment: I'd like too but it is not working out for me yet. I get no channels returned when trying via Java and when trying via api explorer, status is never filled.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the 'youTubeSignupRequired' exception just when trying to fetch a channelist for the authenticated user. Thanks again.