# YouTube REST API to get playlist not working for my channel?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I am trying to get all the playlist feed URLs from the YouTube channel in my iOS application.

Below is the URL to get the XML data consists of the required contents.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thenewboston/playlists?v=2

This is working fine, which results in the response of an XML with data.

But when I change this to my username nothing is retrieved. I have couple of playlists in my channel.

My Attempts:

Attempt 1:

I have googled and cross checked my channel's privacy settings which is Public in default.

Am I making any wrong? Please let me know your comments.

Attempt 2:

When I try like this in browser, http://www.youtube.com/user/myusername

getting "This channel is not available at the moment. Please try again later.".

The same url is working fine for thenewboston.

Comment: It seems like there is some problem with accessing your channel. Have a look at all the settings again.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg  have newly created it, just few hours back. Do you think will it be a problem.

Comment: I think its a problem of the user not being authenticated. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428059/how-to-check-if-a-youtube-channel-is-active).

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg Thanks. But the authentication is no way related to this. If its the authentication problem the url for thenewboston should not work right. Its just a public channel.

Comment: @Nikhita I found the solution and posted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&author=USER_NAME&orderby=published

This will fetch all the user videos.

Comment: When I try this I am getting the xml response but the entry tag doesn't appear. This will contain the information. This doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found the solution and posted the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Below is the format that I have tried.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/playlists?v=2
```

But it seems there is some change in the API.

**To request a feed of another user's playlists, send a GET request to the following URL. This request does not require authentication.In the URL above, you should replace the text userId with the user's YouTube user ID. For backward compatibility purposes, the API also supports having the user's YouTube username specified instead.**

To find the userId in YouTube : (Follow the steps below)

1. Click the arrow on top right after login to your YouTube account.
2. Select YouTube settings.
3. Select the link [Advanced](http://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) and find the YouTube User Id there.

Reference : [YouTube API v.2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists)